# "failed to get the task for process 567" How Solve this?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to load my application in device but i got message like shown in image [image]

How can i solve it ??
I am using xCode 4.5 now and running in the device iOS 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xCode: failed to get the task for process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)

Answer (score 5):

Check that you are using a development provisioning profile, not a distribution one =]

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean the project.
2. Delete derived data.
3. Relaunch the xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove expired certificates on Keychain application.

Answer (score 0):

For me I switched the run scheme to "Debug" instead of "Release", works as expected.