# Could not launch "<appName>" failed to get the task for process <processNumber>?

Tags: xcode, ios6, build-error

Using Xcode 4.5.2 and building for iOS4 or newer, I get this message when building for my device (iOS 6.0.1 on 4s).  I dismiss the dialog then relaunch the app on my device which seems to work.  I am newer to iOS development, so I aplogize in advance if this is a silly question.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your run configuration set to debug?

Comment: Thank you, yes it was.  I changed it, still happening!?!  I am guessing a newbie mistake here....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11601403/1059705

Comment: possible duplicate of [xCode: failed to get the task for process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)

Answer (score 117):

My issue was using Distribution provisioning profile for signing the app, once I made a development provisioning profile, the app installed and ran on iPhone just fine.

Comment: Yayy this worked! So on code signing I changed the 2 Debug rows to "iPhone Developer" instead of "iPhone Distribution" which I had before. I didn't touch release.

Comment: Yes indeed: I was using an adhoc profile for debug in [Build Settings]->[Code Signing]... Switched to development profile, and could launch

Comment: Perfect! Can someone please pass the message on to Apple, to allocate some budget to giving some useful error messages for stuff like this!?

Answer (score 7):

The answer seems to be "**you need to fix your provisioning profile**", but can happen for several reasons, as indicated by other answers on here.

In my case, I hadn't added a new device to an existing developer provisioning profile, so I just re-created the profile with the new device, and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

In my case happens all time I add a new device ID then update the provision profile, download and "install it on Xcode 5".

To fix this:

- Go to Xcode>Preferences>Account Tab>Select Apple ID>View
  Details>Refresh Button (Bottom left corner).
- Reinitiate Xcode.

Start again the app, you will be able to test the app in the device.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what my situation was and how I solved the problem:

- I had been running the app from Xcode to my phone and all was fine
- I switched to a different code signing identity  (I had to change the bundle name also to match)
- I ran the app to my phone and got the error.  The app would install, but not open.
- Did a bunch of stuff like Clean, close n open Xcode; delete the app from the phone. All to no good effect.

SOLUTION: turned the phone off n on.

Coincidence?  I think not.    :-)

Answer (score 0):

XCode 6:

Just create provisioning profile for development and assing it to Project -> Build settings -> Provisioning profile

For upload you have to change provisioning profile for Distribution profile.