# Can't see developer provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting [Could not launch "<appName>" failed to get the task for process <processNumber>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048051/could-not-launch-appname-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-processnumber) again and again.  I can't get XCode to acknowledge the developer profiles I have created under Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Provisioning Profile, only the provisioning profiles.  Is XCode not meant to acknowledge the developer profiles as well?

Comment: You are using the term "developer profiles" in a funny way. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: The iOS developer profile that I get from the developer member centre.

Comment: Did you setup accounts in Xcode settings?

Comment: The only things I see that you can "get from the member center" are Development Certificate, Deployment Certificate, Development Provisioning Profile (for an app), and Deployment Provisioning Profile (for an app). Can you fit the thing you are talking about into one of those boxes?

Comment: Yes to accounts question.  I meant the Development Provisioning Profile (for an app).