# how to debugging the app using mac and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I am trying to run the application on the device connected to mac but I am getting the following error

```
error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/270C374C-EF5E-4DFA-82E4-339FC53EFA91/todo.app' -- failed to get the task for process 178
```

Can anyone suggest how to handle the issue? and  can anyone guide me how to debug using this mode?

Comment: Please do a search before asking. This comes up all the time; I'm sure one of the answers will be of use to you.

Comment: thanks matt I will keep in mind but since i am new to the development i am bit confused

Comment: @Nexttric no level of confusion / lack of knowledge of a platform is an excuse for not simply copying and pasting an error into google and trying something yourself

Answer (score 0):

***Here are few tips which you can try:***

1. Go to **Build Settings** --> **Code Signing** --> **Code Signing Identity** and select iOS Developer.
2. **Command + Shift + k** to clean and then **Command + Shift + b** to build and then **Command + r** to run the project.
3. You can also completely exit the XCode and then start the XCode again.

***Few links you can try:***

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/qa/qa1682/_index.html)

[xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)

[iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)