# Could not launch iOS app task failed for process 10061 via Xcode, after swift 3 conversion

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios10, xcode8

After converting my app to swift 3 and trying to launch on ios10 device I am getting a "failed to get the task for process 10061" error message.  Wish apple could provide me a better error message than this. It runs fine on simulator but crashes on device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be here what causes it and possible solution:

> May be it's because you are either using your Ad Hoc or Distribution
>   Provisioning profile when debugging your iPhone application on your
>   device or you specified a code signing entitlements property list in
>   your build settings which does not include a get-task-allow or "Can be
>   debugged" property.

So, use *Development profile* rather than your Distribution profile when debugging your iPhone application on the device.

> and If you specified a code signing entitlements property list in your
>   build settings, make sure that your property list contains the
>   get-task-allow property.

Check related answer here:[Xcode: failed to get the task for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process)

and

QA link here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1682/_index.html