# Error: failed to get the task for process

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the same Question like this [Xcode: failed to get the task for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601304/xcode-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process/11601406). Every time I want to test my app on my iPhone I get the error "failed to get the task for process". The solution of this thread was to change the settings to the developer certificate as far I understand this. Unfortunately this is not the solution for my. Is there an other way to solve the problem?

Edit: I have checked that "Code Signing Identity" is set to iOS Developer (in project) and "Code Signing Style" is set to Automatic (in target) -> in manual my build will crash. I tried to restart Xcode and my iPhones. I tried to install the app while the iPhone is locked and unlocked it later. Nothing worked :(.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you tried; there are a number of possible solutions listed in the answers you linked.

Comment: ok thank you, I updated the question.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue, the error was:

```
failed to get the task for process 325
```

In my case, I was trying to run the application by selecting the Ad-Hoc signing certificate in the provisioning profile. As soon as I switched it to a Development signing certificate in the provisioning profile, the application started running into my iPhone.

There are many solutions to this. And the above one worked for me.